Pytorch `DataSet.__getitem__()` called with `index` bigger than `__len__()`
I have following torch dataset (I have replaced actual code to read data from files with random number generation to make it minimal reproducible):
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import torch 

class TempDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, window_size=200):
        
        self.window = window_size

        self.x = torch.randn(4340, 10, dtype=torch.float32) # None
        self.y = torch.randn(4340, 3, dtype=torch.float32) 

        self.len = len(self.x) - self.window + 1 # = 4340 - 200 + 1 = 4141 
                                                # Hence, last window start index = 4140 
                                                # And last window will range from 4140 to 4339, i.e. total 200 elements

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len

    def __getitem__(self, index):

        # AFAIU, below if-condition should NEVER evaluate to True as last index with which
        # __getitem__ is called should be self.len - 1
        if index == self.len: 
            print('self.__len__(): ', self.__len__())
            print('Tried to access eleemnt @ index: ', index)
            
        return self.x[index: index + self.window], self.y[index + self.window - 1]

ds = TempDataset(window_size=200)
print('len: ', len(ds))
counter = 0 # no record is read yet
for x, y in ds:
    counter += 1 # above line read one more record from the dataset
print('counter: ', counter)

It prints:
len:  4141
self.__len__():  4141
Tried to access eleemnt @ index:  4141
counter:  4141

As far as I understand, __getitem__() is called with index ranging from 0 to __len__()-1. If thats correct, then why it tried to call __getitem__() with index 4141, when the length of the data itself is 4141?
One more thing I noticed is that despite getting called with index = 4141, it does not seem to return any elements, which is why counter stays at 4141
What my eyes (or brain) are missing here?
PS: Though it wont have any effect, just to confirm, I also tried to wrap DataSet with torch DataLoader and it still behaves the same.

The iterator protocol when you don't define __iter__
What you are seeing here is the standard iteration protocol in Python for a class that does not implement __iter__.
When you write for x, y in ds:, and ds does not have an __iter__ method, what Python runs is equivalent to something like this:
i = 0
while True:
    try:
        x, y = ds[i]
    except IndexError:
        break
    [the body of your loop]
    i = i + 1

What that means in your code
In your code, that IndexError happens at index==4141 because of the window_size parameter:
With window_size=200, self.x[index: index + self.window] is self.x[4141:4341] when index==4141 but your self.x has len 4340. Hence it's that sub-expression that raises the IndexError. This is consistent with your assignment of self.len in __init__ except Python does not rely on that to infer it's at the end, it waits for the IndexError exception.
A minimal example illustrating the iterator protocol
Here's a much shorter example that illustrates all this:
class MySeq:
    data = list(range(10,15))

    def __len__(self):
        print("Called __len__")
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        print(f"Called __getitem__({i=})")
        return self.data[i]

myseq = MySeq()
for x in myseq:
    print(f"Got {x=}")

When you run this, you get this output:
Called __getitem__(i=0)
Got x=10
Called __getitem__(i=1)
Got x=11
Called __getitem__(i=2)
Got x=12
Called __getitem__(i=3)
Got x=13
Called __getitem__(i=4)
Got x=14
Called __getitem__(i=5)

That last line, calling __getitem__(i=5), is going to raise IndexError since len=5 the way I created my example, and that's what stops the iteration.
By contrast, if you add an __iter__ function to this class:
    def __iter__(self):
        print("Called __iter__")
        return iter(self.data)

the output becomes:
Called __iter__
Got x=10
Got x=11
Got x=12
Got x=13
Got x=14

Notice that in either case, __len__ does not get called, that's just not how iteration works in Python. Iteration just continues until an IndexError is raised if you don't implement __iter__. And if you do implement it, then the protocol relies on the StopIteration exception being raised to end iteration.

Now am guessing why the custom dataset example (FaceLandmarksDataset) from the official tutorial neither implements __iter__, nor raise any exception (IndexError or StopIteration) inside __getitem__. Also, if it keeps calling __getitem__ till it encounters exception, then why it stops at index 4141? (Also earlier in the past whenever I tried custom datasets, it used to work fine without __iter__)

My guess is that it stops at 4141 because the body of __getitem__ raises IndexError what that is the index provided, but let me test with your exact code to confirm that.

Question: the line return self.x[index: index + self.window], self.y[index + self.window - 1] should be indented, right? I.e., it is the return statement of __getitem__?

Actually, I don't need to runr the code: with window_size=200. self.x[index: index + self.window] is self.x[4141:4341] when index==4141 but self.x only len 4340. Hence it's that sub-expression that raises the IndexError. This is consistent with your assignment of self.len in __init__ except Python does not rely on that to infer it's at the end.

My next question, however, is in what sense does this not work? What about these results is unexpected or causing problems?

The return statement needs to be indented. Fixed that.

So, you mean to say __getitem__ getting called with index==len is expected behavior. With this call, it results in IndexError which terminates the iteration, right? I was thinking that __getitem__ should never be called with index==len.

Indeed, you should always expect getitem to get called one last time with index == Len, that's how the protocol works.
